# Inheriting an association via another model in Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, authorization, associations, roles

I have a pretty standard User/Role setup going on (a user HABTM roles, a role HABTM users). I'm using CanCanCan for authorisation, and the role you have defines what you can do around the application. This part is all working fine, but now I want to be able to have users inherit roles as part of having a subscription to different memberships.

Here are the models concerned:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_one :membership_subscription
  has_one :membership, through: :membership_subscription
end

class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end

class MembershipSubscription < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :membership
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :membership_subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :membership_subscriptions
end
```

I was thinking that I might be able to just add a `has_many: roles` association to the Membership, and then say that the user `has_many` roles through their subscription to the Membership, as well as the current HABTM association that allows roles to be assigned directly.

This way you can directly attach roles to users like you can now (as some roles are additive, and not related to the membership subscription/type at all) but also users will automatically inherit roles (and lose them again) as their membership subs come and go.

Does that make sense? I guess the other option would be to use callbacks in the model to deal with creating/deleting role associations but it doesn't seem as elegant.

Any advice greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think this is a valid answer:

First, update the models so that there is an associations between the Memberships and the Roles:

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_and_belongs_to_many :memberships
end

class Membership < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :membership_subscriptions
  has_many :users, through: :membership_subscriptions
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
end
```

Next, create a method in the user model that can be used to retrieve both directly assigned roles and inherited roles:

```
def combined_roles
  if self.membership == nil
    self.roles
  else
    self.roles + self.membership.roles
  end
end
```

Then wherever you need to check a role, call that method instead of the usual `user.roles`

Not sure if that's a naive way of doing things, but seems to work okay. Comments still welcome if there's a better way

EDIT:

This allows a user to have the same role multiple times - it can be assigned directly or inherited. Modify the combined_roles method like so so that it strips out duplicates:

```
def combined_roles
  if self.membership == nil
    self.roles
  else
    (self.roles + self.membership.roles).uniq
  end
end
```

Comment: Just one final thing to be aware of - by running `self.roles + self.membership.roles` you convert the ActiveRecord Collection to an Array. So methods like `.where` no longer work. For example, I had to update my `has_role` method to use `self.combined_roles.any? {|h| h[:name] == role_name}` instead of the previous `self.roles.where(:name => role_name).present?`

Comment: You could get roles_ids and membership.roles_ids, merge those arrays and then do `Role.where(id: combined_roles_ids)` to use an activerecord's query instead of an array.